# apache/php/mysqli connection to remote db fails but IIS and MySQL workbench connects

Tags: php, apache, mysqli

I am developing locally and connecting to a remote mysql server. I had been using IIS on my local machine (WinXP) but am now using Apache instead. Most of my PHP site is working correctly after the move to Apache.

But - when mysqli tries to connect to the remote db I get:
(HY000/2003): Can't connect to MySQL server on '***.***.***.***:****' (10060)

I know that the server is accepting connections from my IP because I am able to connect to the same server from my local machine using MySQL Workbench.

I also know that the db connection details I'm using with mysqli are correct because I was using the same details when running on IIS without problem, the only change that happened is that I moved from IIS to Apache.

This problem still exists when my local firewall is disabled.

I have very little experience with Apache, is there perhaps a config setting I've missed that prevents me from connecting out to a remote db, or something that is mangling/hiding reporting of my correct IP?

Thanks for any help, I'm clutching at straws here...

Comment: You may not have the MySQL module installed correctly if you installed Apache separately. Install WAMP or XAMP and it will do Apache, PHP, MySQL for you! :)

Comment: Could you show the PHP code you use to connect to MySQL using mysqli ?

Comment: `$mysqli_connection = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_pwd, $_db);` is the code I used.

Comment: thanks for the WAMP/XAMP suggestion, I had considered it but will wait and see if there is a simpler fix first - I don't need MySQL on my local machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error 10060 happens when the remote MySQL server does not respond.

It could be that connections to port 3306 on the remote machine are being blocked.  It could be that the system hosting PHP/Apache has a software firewall that is blocking the outgoing connection, or that PHP/Apache is not permitted to open network connections by that firewall.

Comment: thanks for the answer - a different port is being used but I can confirm it isn't being blocked by the MySQL server as I am able to connect using the same details and same machines via MySQL Workbench. I've also tried testing with my local firewall disabled - no joy.

Comment: Are you able to connect using PHP at the command line from the machine hosting Apache?

Comment: I've never used PHP from the command line. How do I approach this please, is it a matter of creating a .php file and executing it?

Comment: Yes, then calling it with `php whatever.php`.  You can also just type in the appropriate commands by invoking `php -a` at a command prompt.  (This will require that the `php.exe` file be in your path, or that you're in the PHP program file directory.)

Comment: thanks I created a stripped down .php file executed it at a command prompt - I get exactly the same error message

Comment: Super!  Now, do you still have IIS on that machine?  If so, turn off Apache, turn on IIS, and see if running *that same exact code* also fails when it's back in IIS.

Comment: haha ok, did that and as you may have predicted the connection now no longer works in IIS either. I think you've helped me to establish that I've broken my PHP installation :) Maybe I'll need to follow the suggestion above and do a clean install of WAMP or something, I was hoping to learn by finding and fixing the specific problem rather than chucking it all out and starting again, particularly as this problem is only affecting my dev environment and not the live site.

Comment: I still expect that this is a configuration issue instead of an installation issue, though a clean reinstall never hurts when you're dealing with Windows.

Comment: I think I know where I went wrong. With IIS I had PHP 5.3(compiled with VC9), but I saw that for Apache I needed to be using 5.2(VC6). I extracted the 5.2 package over the old 5.3 package, I have no idea why I did that rather than finding out how to downgrade properly because I wouldn't dream of doing that with any other software installation. I realise I have created quite a messy first post here and am not sure if anybody will gain from it but I think the best I can do is vote this as the best answer as the process at least helped me work out where the problem was. Thanks for helping!

Comment: Aha!  Yeah -- your best bet here might be actually getting a VC9 Apache.  The PHP folks recommended the builds from [Apache Lounge](https://www.apachelounge.com/download/) when they announced that VC6 builds were being discontinued.

Comment: Have installed the VC9 Apache, gone back to PHP 5.3/VC9 and all seems to be working fine - thanks again for the assistance :)